# Java Arrays: From Txt File to an Array

Tags: java, arrays, file

EDIT:
I am a beginner Java programmer and I have assignment that I cannot seem to figure out. 
My instructions read:

```
Program Description:  Read 20 pairs of numbers (ID number and score respectively) into two separate arrays.  Find the average score.  Print a table as shown below of the ID, score and difference (score - average) for each student, one student per line.  Print the sum, average, and count of score at the head of the table as shown.  Round the average and difference to 2 decimal places.

Sample Output:

Sum     =   4853 
Average = 242.65 
Count   =   20 
Id       Score     Diff 
115 257     14.35
123 253     10.35 
116 246       3.35
113 243       0.35 
112 239      -3.65
104 239      -3.65 
110 238      -4.65
218 243       0.35
208 242      -0.65 
222 223    -19.65 
223 230    -12.65
213 229    -13.65 
207 228    -14.65 
203 224    -18.65 
305 265     22.35 
306 262     19.35 
311 256     13.35 
325 246       3.35
321 245       2.35 
323 245       2.35
```

I am confident that I can do the work once I have the data into the arrays, I just cannot seem to get past that initial step. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;
 public class prog402a
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Scanner inFile = null;
    try 
    {
        // Create a scanner to read the file, file name is parameter
        inFile = new Scanner (new File("prg402a.dat.txt"));
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.out.println ("File not found!");
        // Stop program if no file found
        System.exit (0);
    }


    int[] Array = new int[100];


    for (int index = 0; index < Array.length; index++)
    {
        int id = inFile.nextInt();
        int score = inFile.nextInt();

    }
    for (int index = Array.length; index >= 0; index++)
    {
        System.out.println(Array[index]);
    }

}

}
```

Data File:

```
115 257
123 253
116 246
113 243
112 239
104 239
110 238
218 243
208 242
222 223
223 230
213 229
207 228
203 224
305 265
306 262
311 256
325 246
321 245
323 245
302 242
```

Comment: What is your question? This code does not store anything in `Array`.

Comment: What exactly is the problem ?

Comment: That is the problem. I am not sure how to store the data in the array. @Rakhita

Comment: See most recent comment @MattBall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several problems. First, you are reading past the end of the data and the `Scanner` is throwing an exception when it can't find an integer to read. Replace the first `for` loop:

```
for (int index = 0; index < Array.length; index++)
```

with:

```
while (inFile.hasNextInt())
```

Second, you aren't storing the data anywhere. The assignment is to create two arrays, but you are only declaring one. You'll need to fix that. Finally, your last loop (to print the data) is quite wrong. The first time through the loop will crash because 100 is not a legal index for `Array`. Also, you are starting at the top and going down, but you are *incrementing* `index`. Also, I suggest that you keep track of how many data pairs were actually read and use that for your loop limits, rather than `Array.length`. Fix these issues and you should have a program that successfully reads the data and prints it.

EDIT:

Here's a version of your program (untested) that should read the data into two separate arrays (as per the assignment):

```
public class prog402a
{

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner inFile = null;
        try 
        {
            // Create a scanner to read the file, file name is parameter
            inFile = new Scanner (new File("prg402a.dat.txt"));
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.out.println ("File not found!");
            // Stop program if no file found
            System.exit (0);
        }

        int[] ids = new int[100];
        int[] scores = new int[100];
        int count = 0;

        while (inFile.hasNextInt())
        {
            ids[count] = inFile.nextInt();
            scores[count] = inFile.nextInt();
            count++;
        }
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
        {
            System.out.println(ids[index] + " " + scores[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using the while loop but got nowhere with that. I know how to set up the loops, just not how to make it store the correct data which was what my original question was. Can you explain how I might go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in your handling of arrays. for instance in the First for loop how java compiler knows that where to store the value of inFile.nextInt() in Array[index]? each time you are declaring a new variable like int score etc. You need to use index of array to accomplish your job. Here is the code may help you

```
int[] Array = new int[100];


for (int index = 0; index < Array.length; index++)
{
     Array[index]= inFile.nextInt();
     Array[index] = inFile.nextInt();

}
for (int index = Array.length; index >= 0; index++)
{
    System.out.println(Array[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("directory", "data.txt")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    List<Integer> idsList    = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> scoresList = new ArrayList<>();

    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        String[] data = line.split(" ");
        idsList.add( Integer.parseInt(data[0]));
        scoresList.add( Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
        line = reader.readLine();
    }

    reader.close();

    Integer[] idsArray    = (Integer[])idsList.toArray(new Integer[idsList.size()]);
    Integer[] scoresArray = (Integer[])scoresList.toArray(new Integer[idsList.size()]);

    for (int index = 0; index < idsArray.length; index++) {
        System.out.println(idsArray[index] + " " + scoresArray[index]);
    }
}
```

A `BufferedReader` allows you to read line by line. A `List` allows you to work with dynamic lists. The `toArray` method converts the `List` into a regular array. `Integer.parseInt` converts Strings into ints. This is not the best way to code this. I tried to not modify your code too much so you might still be able to understand it.

There are several improvements that could be made in the code (catch the IO exceptions, call `close()` in a finally block (our autocloseable try-with-resources), check for NumberFormatExceptions, etc.